# Pyomo Util Module Not Found

Tags: pyomo, utilities, extras

So I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51044262/finding-out-reason-of-pyomo-model-infeasibility/51044577#51044577) a month ago. I had a really nice answer to that question. I wanted to test if the answer works right now. But I am getting `ModuleNotFoundError`.

I did following before testing:

```
conda install -c conda-forge pyomo
conda install -c conda-forge pyomo.extras
```

I want to run this script in my code (copy/pasted from the other question):

```
from pyomo.util.infeasible import log_infeasible_constraints
...
SolverFactory('your_solver').solve(model)
...
log_infeasible_constraints(model)
```

Error I encounter:

```
N:\urbs>python runme.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "runme.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pyomo.util.infeasible import log_infeasible_constraints
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyomo.util.infeasible'
```

How to install it then? I checked doc etc..., could not find a way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pyomo 5.5 (the latest released version as of 23 August 2018) does not yet have that feature. I had mistakenly assumed that it was included. You can either change your version of pyomo to track `master`, or more easily, you can simply take the function at https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/blob/master/pyomo/util/infeasible.py and place it in your own code (along with the associated required imports).