# Any way to return the active constraints of a solved model in pyomo?

Tags: pyomo

Using a concrete model that successfully solves. Is there any way to retrieve the ACTIVE constraints?

Comment: You can inspect the slack in all constraints and infer from there.  This answer shows how:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51044262/finding-out-reason-of-pyomo-model-infeasibility/70910431#70910431

Answer (score 0):

"Active" is a bit tricky, as that is technically an internal state of the solver (that most solvers don't report).  You can get a reasonable approximation of active constraints with the method:

```py
pyomo.util.infeasible.log_close_to_bounds()
```

...or look at what that method is doing (it's only 40 lines of code) and implement something specific to your use case.